# Server side implementation using Python/(GAE) for push notifications for Android app

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

From where (useful links)should start (I need the basics) to  **Write Server side implement using PYTHON(GAE)** for **push notifications for **"android"** app?

Comment: This link may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697096/google-cloud-messaging-http-error-400-bad-request

Answer (score 2):

Google has a great introduction to setting up push notifications using their new system: Google Cloud Messaging. For more info see the getting started guide here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Since you are using google app engine, check out the demo app that uses app engine. Here is the server side code segment for app-engine users:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html#appengine-setup