# Server side implementation using PYTHON(GAE) for push notifications for “android” app

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server side implementation using Python/(GAE) for push notifications for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276226/server-side-implement-using-pyhtongae-for-push-notifications-for-android-app)

From where(useful links) I should start(i need the basics for startup ) to Write Server side implement using PYTHON(GAE) for push notifications for **"android" app.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open-source project that already implements this in python: [python-gcm](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm)

Comment: Have you actually used this and got it working? I'm not even able to do `from gcm import *;GCM` -- `NameError: name 'GCM' is not defined`, and the documentation for that package does not say what to import

Comment: For the version that I installed via `pip install python-gcm`, I had to import via `from gcm.gcm import GCM`