# Bad request response from Google cloud messaging server, using urllib2

Tags: python, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to send messages to the GCM server using python `urllib2`. But it has been returning `Error 400` (suggesting `Malformed JSON`). This is a very similar question to [Google Cloud Messaging HTTP Error 400: Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697096/google-cloud-messaging-http-error-400-bad-request) but I have already tried the solution provided there, which did not work for me.

Please find my code below

```
idarr = []
for obj in objects:
    idarr.append(str(obj["gcid"]))

key =  "AIzaxxxxxxL9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWbk"
data = { "registration_ids": idarr , "data": "on" }
data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization": "key="+key}
request = urllib2.Request('https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',data,headers )
f=urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Also  I am presenting here the json I am posting in the data field

```
{
    "data": "on", 
    "registration_ids": [
         "APA91bEPvyQuqRndnwZ94YxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxnmFVPy6nv4mPU5UyhDEZ7Jha9HnrV9nXQf25ojs8Hc_-Bw8-ElJ320koeL0PGL6hnWj0xuyltozoND_x",
         "APA91bEPvyQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxVPy6nv4mPU5UyhDEZ7Jha9HnrV9nXQf25ojs8Hc_-Bw8-ElJ320koeL0PGL6hnWj0xuyltozoND_x"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well, your JSON is fine, so that's not your problem. The other question had no accepted answer, and you have *plenty* of reputation to comment on the other question (50 points is all it takes).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, A small confusion from my part. Thanks

Comment: Does `print f.read()` show anything useful? Perhaps Google provided you with a more detailed error message. Also inspect the headers (`print f.info().headers`) to see if there are any clues there as to what might be wrong.

Comment: I am actually getting a python module error.        urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: Of course, it's an exception. The exception has the same information though; use `try: f=urllib2.urlopen(request)`, `except urllib2.HTTPError, e: print e.hdrs, e.read()`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError for more information on the exception.